# Ошибка времени выполнения: Попытка считывания за концом текстового файла

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Вот я заполнил немного файл

```
var
t:text;
s:string;
begin
assign(t,'vlados');
rewrite(t);
writeln(t,123,' ',647);
writeln(t,934);
writeln(t,204,' ',184);
writeln(t,298,' ',187);
writeln(t,475);
close(t);
end.
```

И запустил эту программу(Строка с ошибкой указана):

```
var
b:boolean;
s,m:integer;
t:text;
begin
  writeln('Введите номер:');readln(m);
  assign(t,'vlados');
  reset(t);
  while not eof(t) do
  begin
    read(t,s);{Тут он пишет: Ошибка времени выполнения: Попытка считывания за концом текстового файла}
    if s=m then
      b:=true;
  end;
  close(t);
  if b then
    writeln('Хватайте!')
    else writeln('Пропустите!')
end.
```

Что не так я сделал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение

```
var
b:boolean;
s,m:integer;
t:text;
begin
  writeln('Введите номер:');readln(m);
  assign(t,'vlados');
  reset(t);
  s:=0;
  while not eof(t) and (s<>m) do{Тут нужно добавить: and (s<>m)}
  begin
    read(t,s);
    if s=m then
      b:=true;
  end;
  close(t);
  if b then
    writeln('Хватайте!')
    else writeln('Пропустите!')
end.
```